# Summing a list of OptionT[Future, BigDecimal] in Scalaz

Tags: scala, sum, scalaz

I have a list of type `List[Result[BigDecimal]]` that I want to sum.

`type Result[A] = OptionT[Future, A]`

The rule would be that if there is any `Future(None)` then we get the result `Future(None)`.

I have the function [[1](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/sum+function.html)]:

```
def sum[A: Monoid](as: List[A]): A = {
  val M = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
  as.foldLeft(M.zero)(M.append)
}
```

However, I am missing the `Monoid` instance for `Result[BigDecimal]`. How do I define it using *Scalaz*?

[learning Scalaz - sum function](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/sum+function.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why Scalaz doesn't provide this instance—it does provide a `Monoid[Future[A]]` where `A` has a monoid instance, and where there's an implicit execution context in scope. You can easily make your own, though, <del>either by defining an isomorphism between `Result` and `Future[Option[?]]` and then using `IsomorphismMonoid`, or</del> [this wouldn't actually have the desired semantics] by just defining one directly:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Result[A] = OptionT[Future, A]

implicit def resultMonoid[A: Monoid]: Monoid[Result[A]] = new Monoid[Result[A]] {
  def zero: Result[A] = Monoid[A].zero.point[Result]
  def append(f1: Result[A], f2: => Result[A]): Result[A] = (f1 |@| f2)(_ |+| _)
}
```

And then (using Scalaz's own `suml`, but your `sum` would work as well):

```
scala> List(OptionT(Future(1.some)), OptionT(Future(2.some))).suml
res1: scalaz.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int] = OptionT(List())

scala> scala.concurrent.Await.result(res1.run, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

For what it's worth, [Cats provides this instance](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/OptionT.scala#L202), but (like the `Future[Option[?]]` instance in Scalaz) it has `None` as identity.